# Magic Player init error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need help desperately, i have a lack of knowledge in java scripts and never got this error before, and it is causing some problems in my scripts... this is the error

```
<pre> 
    magicplayer:init: set version: extension=1.0.3 engine=3000500
    init.js:15 onMessageFromBackground: method=statPixel
</pre>
```

these are my scripts that i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed ace stream recently and included browser plugins? I have seen this error in chrome where the extension for AS Magic Player is enabled.